# Position 0 0 on array bidimensional doesn't save a integer

Tags: c

this is my first post on stackoverflow. I had a trobuble with my program and my teacher doesn't know what happends and he recommended ask to stackoverflow (You deserve his salary ). 
Well, this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_X 3
#define MAX_Y 3
#define SYMBOL_X "X"
#define SYMBOL_Y "Y"
#define SYMBOL_EMPTY -1
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

void printBoard(int board[MAX_X][MAX_Y]){
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",board[0][0],board[1][0],board[2][0]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",board[0][1],board[1][1],board[2][1]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",board[0][2],board[1][2],board[2][2]);
    printf("\n");
}
void fillboard(int board[MAX_X][MAX_Y]){
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_Y; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_X; ++j){
            board[j][i]=SYMBOL_EMPTY;
        }
    }
}
int findEmptyBox(int board[MAX_X][MAX_Y])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_Y; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_X; ++j){
            if(board[j][i]=SYMBOL_EMPTY)return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
int checkBoxIntroduced(int x,int y){
    if((x!=0 && x!=1 && x!=2) || (y!=0 && y!=1 && y!=2)){
        printf("Alguna de las casillas no ha sido introducida correctamente\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
void introducirFichaConDialogos(int board[MAX_X][MAX_Y],int player){
    int x,y;
    do{
    printf("Introduce la posicion X: \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Introduce la posicion Y: \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    }while(!checkBoxIntroduced(x,y));
    if(player==0)board[x][y]=1;
    else board[x][y]=2;
}
void checkPlayer(int *pplayer){
    if(*pplayer==1)*pplayer=0;
    else *pplayer=1;
}
void main(){
    int x=0,y=0,board[MAX_X][MAX_Y],i,j,player=0;
    fillboard(board);
    do{
        system("clear");
        printBoard(board);
        introducirFichaConDialogos(board,player);
        checkPlayer(&player);
    }while(!findEmptyBox(board));
}
```

My problem is that only board[0][0] doesn't save the symbol and me and my teacher don't know what is happening and why only is the position 0 0. 
Thanks for help and if someone have and advice I will grateful.

Comment: What does it save?

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more detail? What line or function are you asking about? What do you mean it "doesn't save the symbol"--what is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc throws up a lot of warnings when compiling this code:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/board: gcc -o board -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall board.c
board.c: In function âfindEmptyBoxâ:
board.c:33: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
board.c: At top level:
board.c:60: warning: return type of âmainâ is not âintâ
board.c: In function âmainâ:
board.c:64: warning: implicit declaration of function âsystemâ
board.c:61: warning: unused variable âjâ
board.c:61: warning: unused variable âiâ
board.c:61: warning: unused variable âyâ
board.c:61: warning: unused variable âxâ
```

The first warning is complaining about the following:

```
if(board[j][i]=SYMBOL_EMPTY)return FALSE;
```

You are *assigning* `SYMBOL_EMPTY` to `board[j][i]`, not *comparing* them to each other.  Since `SYMBOL_EMPTY` is non-zero, the value of the assignment expression is non-zero, so the function immediately returns `FALSE`.

Change that to

```
if(board[j][i] == SYMBOL_EMPTY) return FALSE;
```

and you'll be able to assign to 0,0.

A common practice when comparing against constant expressions is to put the constant on the left-hand side of the `==` operator, like so:

```
if ( SYMBOL_EMPTY == board[i][j] )
```

That way, if you accidentally write `=` instead of `==`, the compiler will catch it and issue a diagnostic (a constant expression cannot be the target of an assignment statement).  This doesn't help when both operands are variables, and I've never written comparisons this way myself, but it can be helpful.

The next warning is complaining about

```
void main()
```

`main` returns `int`, not `void`; change that to

```
int main( void )
```

While that isn't your main problem (the `=` instead of `==` was), it is something you want to fix.  There are some oddball platforms out there that will choke on a program that uses `void main()`.

You'll also want to include `stdlib.h` to get rid of the "implicit declaration of function system" warning.

You should also get rid of any unused variables, but that's not critical, and not the problem you're facing right now.

Comment: Thanks John. That was so helpfull. Just one more thing, when I compile, I just use gcc -o. Can you explain me how it works your compiler's sentence?

Comment: Look [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) for a list of options to gcc.  `-std=c99` means to compile against the 1999 language standard.  `-pedantic` will warn about or reject code that uses non-standard extensions.  `-Wall` enables all warnings.  An additional flag, `-Werror`, would treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: Thank you again. I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 4):

The array do save the value in

```
if(board[j][i]=SYMBOL_EMPTY)return FALSE;
```

and only `board[0][0]` is affected because `SYMBOL_EMPTY` is non-zero, so the control will return from the function.

Do you mean comparision instead of the assignment? e.g.

```
if(board[j][i]==SYMBOL_EMPTY)return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison expression should be written this way:

```
const int VAR = 0;

int main(void) {
    if(VAR==3) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

so, if you forget one `=` you obtain a compilation error:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:6:9: error: assignment of read-only variable 'VAR'
  if(VAR =3) return 1;
```